# Self referencing Struct type using python Ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have node class like this:

```
@dataclass
class TreeNode:
    type: NodeType
    tok: Token = None
    children: list = field(default_factory=list)
```

Here, `children` is a list which contains other `TreeNode`s which are children of the parent node. I'm trying to create a `ctypes` structure which replicates the class above so I can send a `TreeNode` object to a C++ function from python. It looks like this:

```
class CTreeNode(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", c_int32), ("tok", CToken), ("children", POINTER('CTreeNode') * 100)]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
SystemError: <class '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'> returned NULL without setting an exception
```

I've looked at the documentation which says arrays can be defined like so

```
("point_array", POINT * 4)
```

But how do I do it by referencing `CTreeNode` inside `CTreeNode` using ctypes. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To make a self-referencing structure, declare the structure without `_fields_`, then add `_fields_` to the structure's class, e.g.:

```
import ctypes as ct

class CToken(ct.Structure):  # undefined in question
    pass

class CTreeNode(ct.Structure):
    # Define a display representation of this structure
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'CTreeNode(type={self.type})'

# Class above exists, now can self-reference when creating _fields_
CTreeNode._fields_ = (("type", ct.c_int32),
                      ("tok", CToken),
                      ("next", ct.POINTER(CTreeNode)))

# Build a link list...adding to head of list each time
root = None
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    tmp = root
    root = ct.pointer(CTreeNode(i))
    root.contents.next = tmp

# Walk the linked list
current = root
while current:
    print(current.contents)
    current = current.contents.next
```

Output:

```
CTreeNode(type=1)
CTreeNode(type=2)
CTreeNode(type=3)
CTreeNode(type=4)
CTreeNode(type=5)
```